# Drag and drop between different table views

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtableview

I have two different Qtable views (I'm using QT) and I don't know how to implement drag&drop functionality between them. It seems to work only when dealing with a single model view (drag&dropping inside the same table). Can someone give me a simple example?